# Idk why i have a declaration syntax error(I'm just a beginner)

Tags: syntax-error, turbo-c++

[image]

Here it says "declaration syntax error"

Expected it to run without errors

Comment: Why are you using this obsolete thing?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a semi-colone on line 6.

```
char ch1 = 'a';
```